# How to know if form is submitted without errors in puppeteer

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to submit a [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFQyn.jpg) and I am testing for cases where the form won't submit due to invalid input. If the zip code I enter is valid, then this line of code will return null because there was no error message.

```
await self.page.waitForFunction(
    'document.querySelector("#adr-zip-error")'
  );
```

However I have to hard code a delay before this or set some kind of timeout to catch this error message.
I tried also checking if the form itself is null in the same way but again, it only works if I check after some amount of time as it takes time for the form to submit.

Is there a way to tell if a form is submitted successfully without using a hard coded delay?

Comment: There is not a general way because not every form submission necessarily generates navigation request. an example would be a multi step form. is it for a specific site? if yes, can you include an example?

Comment: the website is shipt.com but you need to login to see the edit address option on it which is where I am having this problem. This form does not generate a navigation request. Is  there no other way to check the response on a form if it does not navigate somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a general solution and is tailored to this problem. You could use [`waitForResponse`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md#pagewaitforresponseurlorpredicate-options)

```js
const response = await page.waitForResponse(response => response.url().startsWith("https://app.shipt.com/api/v1/customer_addresses"));
if (response.ok())
//success
```

or, you could just check input validity:

```js
const invalid = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#adr-zip').getAttribute('aria-invalid') === "true");
```

Comment: the first one worked perfectly. for some reason the second one evaluated to true regardless of the form submitting correctly or not. may I ask how you got the proper url to use for the response? did you just locate it in the network tab of dev tools?

Comment: @BillTaha yeah, tested it a couple of times to figure out the pattern

Answer (score 1):

After the submit you could do something like:

```
await Promise.race([
  page.waitFor('#adr-zip-error'),
  page.waitForNavigation()
])
```

and then

```
let error = await page.$('#adr-zip-error')
```

will let you know if the error happened first